# Spring Boot: Export identifier encountered more than once

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Following error occures

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:Export identifier [order_signal] encountered more than once
```

I have the following classes:

### tradingbot.persistence.model.order.TransactionComponent

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TransactionComponent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    ...
}
```

### tradingbot.persistence.model.order.OrderSignal

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName("OrderSignalDAO")
public class OrderSignal extends TransactionComponent {
    ...
}
```

### tradingbot.persistence.model.order.TransferSignal

```
@Entity(name = "TransferSignal")
public class TransferSignal extends TransactionComponent {
    ....
}
```

In class OrderSignal there is no other @Id and there is no getter/setter for id in TransactionComponent as well.

Why does this error occures? What does it mean? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use IntelliJ for development and in my "out" directory were old .class files. Some of the java classes already have been deleted, but somehow not in the "out" directory.

As solution I deleted the whole "out" directory.

Answer (score 7):

One Scenario I came across in which the above issue happens is say the entity class would be as follows

```
`@Entity
 @Table(name = "universe")
 public class Universe {
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "universeSequenceGenerator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "universe"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            }
    )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "universeSequenceGenerator")
    private Integer id;
    private String name; 
    ....`
```

In above scenario the following error would be thrown Caused by: `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:Export identifier [universe] encountered more than once`

It is because of  `@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "universe")` , when we change this to `@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "universeSeq")` the error disappears. If the entity name matches anywhere in the parameter names or etc,. then this might occur.

Comment: That was the case for me too, strange that unrelated things conflict together...

Answer (score 0):

I tried @R.Schaefer's solution by deleting the `target/` "out" directory but it didn't work, so I tried to rename the entity and then It worked for me.